# Is it possible to join two separate kubernetes clusters?

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployments on one Kubernetes cluster that I might want to move to another Kubernetes cluster in the future. Is it possible to combine these two clusters or must I redeploy everything? If the answer is yes, what if there are StatefulSets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You can connect to clusters with something like [Kubernetes Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/) or if you have Calico, you can use something like [BGP peering](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/usage/configuration/bgp)

You'll have to redeploy everything and in the case of StatefulSets, it really depends where you are storing your state. For example:

- Is it MySql? Backup your db and restore it in the new place.
- Is it Cassandra? Can you reattach the same physical volumes in the cloud provider? if not, then you'll have to transfer your data.
- Is it etcd, Consul or Zookeeper? Can you back it up or attach the same physical volumes?